# How do i split a single row of columns into multiple rows and columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet

I've looked all over and either I am not sure how to word this for searching, or there just isn't anything out there. Originally, the information in my excel sheet was pulled from a text file. I had to go through a lot of work (delimiting and a lot of find/replace) just to get it to even transfer properly into excel, and it still isn't right, but I guess it will do. Unfortunately, it placed everything into one single row (i.e. A1, B1, C1, etc). I need the information to be split into multiple rows;

```
     A | B
1 | id | 219832
2 | id | 2398
3 | id | 0382
etc
```

Either that, or every other cell being considered part of the header and the cell following to be placed in the proper column;

```
     A  |  B   |   C   |   D
1 | id  | type | label | date
2 | 232 |  A   |  Here | 12/12/12
3 | 643 |  B   | There | 10/14/11
4 | 832 |  A   | None  | 09/29/13
etc
```

This is how this appears as data, currently

```
    id | TTXW5IAXBSWDETCQZKGUNKK2RYKOVVFQ4S3VGCV | type | A | Label | Here | date | 12/12/12 | id 
etc
```

If someone can help me do this, I would appreciate it very much. While the second option would be much more helpful to me, as that is what I really need to transfer all of this information into, the first option would be acceptable as I can just work by hand from there. Also, just so you know how huge this is, my row extends out to JON1.

Edit:

Also, without all of the find/replace (some but not nearly as much), the data gets pasted into each cell as;

```
"id":"TTXW5IAXBSWDETCQZKGUNKK2RYKOVVFQ4S3VGCV"
```

And this is how this way looks

```
    "id":"TTXW5IAXBSWDETCQZKGUNKK2RYKOVVFQ4S3VGCV" | "type":"A" | "label":"Here" | "date":"12/12/12" | {"id": 
etc
```

or something similar. If that would be easier to work with, then that would be fine as well. I am also noticing, from browsing the data, that not every line of data will begin with "id" though, without using find/replace to get rid of it, the beginning of new lines of data do have a { in front of it;

```
{"type":"A" |
{"id":"3242134" |
like that
```

Comment: Maybe an example of a row as you have it and the desired outcome could help to a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Can you upload your excel file?

Comment: No, that I cannot legally do. The file has extremely sensitive information within it.

Comment: Do you still have the source data and if so, can you describe its structure?  I'm just wondering if there might be a way to redo this from scratch that would be more efficient than starting from the current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is through VBA. I suppose that there is a "field" on each cell on row 1, like this

```
{"id" : "TTXW5IAXBSWDETCQZKGUNKK2RYKOVVFQ4S3VGCV" | "type" : "A" | "label": "Here"
```

You have to go to macro, and create a new one, insert the following code:

```
 Sub test()
        Dim wks As Worksheet
        Set wks = ActiveSheet
        Final = False
        i = 1
        InitialRow = 2
        Dim labels(0 To 4) As String
        labels(0) = "id"
        labels(1) = "type"
        labels(2) = "label"
        labels(3) = "grouping"
        labels(4) = "created"
        While Final = False
            ThisCell = Trim(wks.Cells(1, i))
            iniChar = Left(ThisCell, 1)
            If iniChar = "{" Then
                lengthCell = Len(ThisCell)
                ThisCell = Trim(Right(ThisCell, lengthCell - 1))
                InitialRow = InitialRow + 1
            End If
            PosLabelinCell = InStr(ThisCell, ":")
            LabelinCell = Trim(Left(ThisCell, PosLabelinCell - 1))
            lLabelinCell = Len(LabelinCell)
            DatainCell = Trim(Mid(ThisCell, PosLabelinCell + 1))
            lDatainCell = Len(DatainCell)
            LabelinCell = Mid(LabelinCell, 2, lLabelinCell - 2)
            DatainCell = Mid(DatainCell, 2, lDatainCell - 2)
            Select Case LabelinCell
                Case labels(0)
                    wks.Cells(InitialRow, 1) = DatainCell
                Case labels(1)
                    wks.Cells(InitialRow, 2) = DatainCell
                Case labels(2)
                    wks.Cells(InitialRow, 3) = DatainCell
                Case labels(3)
                    wks.Cells(InitialRow, 4) = DatainCell
                Case labels(4)
                    wks.Cells(InitialRow, 5) = DatainCell
            End Select
            i = i + 1
            If wks.Cells(1, i) = "" Then
                Final = True
            End If
        Wend
End Sub
```

It will go through all the cells in the first row and check if a cell starts with the symbol **{**, assuming this as a *newline* character. If a label is missing from the 4 you provide me (id, type, label, grouping,created) it wil leave a blank cell.

Now, run the macro with F5 or with the  green "play" button; from row 3 there will be all the data organized by columns.

Comment: Correct. The id field is not always the first field of an entry, for some unknown reason. Considering this, how would this be redone for the second type of fields ( {"id":"whatever" )? At least with it, it could be used to place each entry on a new row. Either that, or using it to search for certain values and only place those in new rows. I am trying to remake it and ~70% of the fields are no longer required.

Comment: I can change the VBA script if I know which are the lables that I can find (for example, id, type,name,etc).

Comment: The labels I need are;

`id
type
label
grouping
created`

Those 5 are all I need to get ordered into a proper system for replacement.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the Macro Excel, I changed it, so it will work whenever it finds data this way:  
    {"type":"A" |
    {"id":"3242134" |
    like that

Comment: It isn't working. Only thing that happens is it turns Final.

Comment: This script assumes that the data is in row 1 starting on A1 with something like:

`Cell A1 = {id`

then

`Cell B1 = TTXW5IAXBSWDETCQZKGUNKK2RYKOVVFQ4S3VGCV`

and 

`Cell C1 = type`

and

`Cell D1 = A`

and so on ...

Is it true?

Comment: No. Each cell is as above A1 = {"id":"34234" A2 = "type":"a" etc

Comment: That one worked. Had to add another if to check the length of the Data and ensure it was over 2 before removing the ", but I have my fixed table. Thank you very much. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel inbuilt feature.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to **Data** tab.
2. In the **Data Tools** group you will see **"Text to Columns"** Click on that.

Now follow the instruction in the Convert Text to Column Wizard as per your need.

If that not help you, provide one Input Row and Desired Output.

Comment: Excel complains that only one column at a time may be selected. Considering the entire thing consists of 1 row and 7000+ columns, that will not work.